# check if a record exist in Sql with C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

In my SQL Server database, I have records which are increments and sometimes I have some gaps in ID increments.

```
ID      Data     Data

9857370  Data   (null)
9857371 (null)  (null)
9857375 (null)  (null)  
9857376 (null)  (null)
```

We can see a gap in the increment of the ID.

EDIT :

I use C# with SQL for a ASP.net project.
With a SQL request I select the Last ID in my database and in C# with OleDbDataReader I check each record if he hasn't (null) (null) like in my example and I decrement my ID until to have a Data in a column.

But I can't check my record when he has a jump between 2 records.

```
 ID      Data     Data

9857371  (null)  (null)
9857375  (null)  (null)
```

Comment: `select count(*) from yourtable where id=$id`, basically, and see what the count comes back as. 0 = no matching row.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What is the problem? Look at the first comment. It's absolutely easy. Or you're making the worng question.if som, please, edit it.

Comment: How is this related to C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have resolve my problem !

My problem was to access to a data in Database but with records without data (in example between 9857371 and 9857375)  or records null ( 9857376 (null)  (null)).

```
ID      Data     Data

9857370  Data   (null)
9857371 (null)  (null)
9857375 (null)  (null)  
9857376 (null)  (null)
```

Here is my code to access to a data with a loop, hope It will help someone

```
public void main(string url)
 {
     int var = 0;
     string conn = url;


     OleDbConnection connexion = new OleDbConnection(conn);
     connexion.Open();

     OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT ID, DATA1, DATA2 from Database WHERE ID = ( SELECT MAX (ID) -" + var + " FROM Database);", connexion);
     OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     reader.Read();



     if (connexion.State == ConnectionState.Open)
     {


         if (!reader.HasRows || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(reader[1].ToString())) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(reader[2].ToString())))
         {

             reader.Close();

             OleDbDataReader reader2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
             reader2.Read();

         Found:
             while (!reader2.HasRows || ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(reader2[1].ToString())) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(reader2[2].ToString()))))
             {


                 var++;

                 reader2 = fonction(var, url);
                 reader2.Read();
                 if (!reader2.HasRows)
                 {
                     goto Found;
                 }
                 else if (((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(reader2[1].ToString())) || (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(reader2[2].ToString()))))
                 {

                     data = reader2[1].ToString() + " " + reader2[2].ToString();

                 }
                 else
                 {
                     data = "No Data in Database";
                 }

             }

             reader2.Close();
         }
         else
         {

             data = reader[1].ToString() + " " + reader[2].ToString();
         }

     }
     else
     {
         data = "Connexion KO";
     }



     reader.Close();
     connexion.Close();

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use `Recursive CTE` to generate the ID's between Maximum and Minimum ID's in your table. Then use `LEFT join` the CTE with table to get the missing rows.

```
DECLARE @MaxID INT = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Tablename)
DECLARE @MinID INT = (SELECT Min(ID) FROM Tablename)

;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT @MinID fullid 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT fullid + 1 FROM CTE WHERE fullid < @MaxID
    )
SELECT fullid as MissingId FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN dbo.Tablename t on t.ID = CTE.fullid 
WHERE t.ID isNULL
GO
```

Comment: Using a rCTE to count is really poor from a performance perspective. It works but it really still doing row by row logic. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Answer (score 0):

I generally have a Numbers table ready, which includes only one column and all the numbers from 1 to n (n can be doubled easily whenever necessary). Then use a simple query to find the first unused number. Like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 NUMBER FROM NUMBERS
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID = N)
ORDER BY NUMBER
```

Simple and quite fast, assuming columns Number and ID are indexed.

Edit: How to create and populate the numbers table.

```
CREATE TABLE NUMBERS(NUMBER INT)
GO
INSERT INTO NUMBERS VALUES(1)
```

And execute the following whenever you need to double the number of numbers (1, 2, 4, 8, ...)

```
INSERT INTO NUMBERS
SELECT (SELECT MAX(NUMBER) FROM NUMBERS) + NUMBER FROM NUMBERS
```